# Pandas returns empty dataframe when loading multiple .csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm absolutely confused as to why this is not working as I don't get an error message.

I have been trying to load multiple .csv files from a folder (all have the same format as they have been collected from the PubMed API) into a single dataframe.

This is my code:

```
path = "~/Desktop/PubMed/Corpus"

files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in files]
print(dfs)
```

This returns just this:

```
[]
```

Afterwards, I tested if a single file could be loaded and it can be!

Any help is appreciated to solve this.

Comment: What return `print (files)` ?

Comment: @jezrael the same [] - could it be glob?

Comment: What is output of `import os;print(os.path.exists("~/Desktop/PubMed/Corpus"))`

Comment: @Daweo the output is False - however how does this make sense when I can load a single file?

Comment: @msa what operating system are you using?

Comment: @Daweo im on the latest mac version and using the PyCharm IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*latest mac version*

I am not sure as I did not work on it, but I suspect problem might be caused by using `~` as

> Unlike a unix shell, Python does not do any automatic path expansions.

Please try using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) which should take care of it i.e. replace

```
path = "~/Desktop/PubMed/Corpus"
```

using

```
import os
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/PubMed/Corpus")
```

Comment: thank you this worked! could you please explain to me why my version did not work?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what might be wrong with `glob`, but I'd suggest using `os.listdir` as a workaround and then check in your list comprehension wether `f` has the right extension:

```
files = os.listdir(path)
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in files if f.split('.')[-1] == 'csv']
```

Comment: for some reason, this returns a path not found error.